# HQL - passing list of objects to Custom query method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I want to get some data from db using custom query.

```
   @Query("select new com.myProject.UserConfDTO(cd.id, us.lastDeactivationTime, true) from UserConfig us " +
            "join us.codes as cd where cd in :codes and us.userEnabled = 1 and us.state= 'ACTIVE'")
    List<UserConfDTO> getAllEnabledUsersWithConf(@Param("codes") List<Codes> codes);
```

Codes.java:

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
public class Codes{
    private  Integer id;
    private  String name;
    }
```

UserConfDTO.java:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserConfDTO{
    private  Integer id;
    private  String name;
    private  Instant lastDeactivationTime;
    private  Boolean userEnabled;
}
```

UserConfig.java:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@ElementCollection
@Builder.Default
private Set<Integer> codes = new HashSet<>();

private Instant lastDeactivationTime;
@Column(nullable = false)
private State state;
```

I would like to pass all Codes objects - check some things in db, and return prepared UserConfDT object. Unfortunately, It doesn`t work. I get exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [Codes(id=1234, name=test1)] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
```

I have UserConfig class/table with relation one-many with class/table Codes. One UserConfig can have more then one codes.
I want to pass List as parameter and fetch from UserConfig data (by each Codes ID property) --> next create via (select new..) UserConfDTO object.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. You're trying to test if `cd.id` which is an Integer, is contained in a List<Codes>. That makes no sense: a List<Codes> can't possibly contain an Integer. You can check if a Codes (i.e. `cd`, not `cd.id`) is contained in a List<Codes>, or if an Integer is contained in a List<Integer>, though.

Comment: Ok, I understand it. Thanks @JB Nizet. But when I check if a Codes is contained in a List : `@Query("select new com.myProject.UserConfDTO(cd.id, us.lastDeactivationTime, true) from UserConfig us " +
            "join us.codes as cd where cd in :codes and us.userEnabled = 1 and us.state= 'ACTIVE'")
    List<UserConfDTO> getAllEnabledUsersWithConf(@Param("codes") List<Codes> codes);` - get the same exception because of Codes table in my db. I have UserConfig table with relation one to many with Codes(UserConfigId, Code) table.

Comment: I know that there is SpEL and tried this:`join us.codes as cd where cd in :#{#codes.id} ` but then I got exception: `SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public?`

Comment: I don't see how you could get the same exception. A different one, maybe, but not the same.

Comment: I tried to do it in SpEL, but have no idea how to get id property from all elements of the list. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: All you need is `where cd in :codes`.

Comment: @JBNizet , then I got `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element [Code(id=1234, name=test1)] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)];`

Comment: CODES are integers in my DB. I would like to fetch all CODES with id equals to all Codes.id list element (which I pass to method)

Comment: It's very, very unclear. Post your entities. How can codes be integers and have an ID at the same time?

Comment: You need to pass a Set<Integer> instead of a List<Codes> to your method. Or you need to write it as a custom method, that extracts the IDs from the List<Codes>, and execute the query.